# Segue to UITableViewCell from MapKit Annotation with a touch of Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, mapkit

I am trying to segue from a MapKit Annotation (i) button to a UITableViewCell. To accomplish this I am using the following code:

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

    let annotation = view.annotation as! MKPointAnnotation
    let uid = annotation.title
    self.userkey = uid!
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetailFromMap", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetailFromMap" {

        let detailTVC = segue.destination as! MediaDetailTableViewController

        let value = self.userkey

        print(value)

        let ref2 = DatabaseReference.media.reference()
        let query2 = ref2.queryOrdered(byChild: "uid").queryEqual(toValue: (value))

        query2.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

            let media = Media(dictionary: snapshot.value as! [String : Any])


            print(snapshot.value)

            self.media1 = media
         })

        detailTVC.media = media1
        detailTVC.currentUser = currentUser

    }
}
```

I made a print statement in the tableViewController's cellForRow at as print(user.uid) and this is throwing an "unexpectedly found nil" The print statement after the firebase reference is not returning anything so I think this is starting with a firebase error. The firebase query is not running so media is never getting a value. I've done successful queries with this format many times before but it is not working now. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

I moved the query inside the map function and included self.performSegue in the completion block and it works now.